# VBA Help - Run Time Error 5: Invalid Procedure Call or Argument, only at first-run

Tags: vba, copy, runtime-error

It reports "Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument" at line 37 "sh_DP_old.Copy After:=sh_new" only at the first-run. After clicking "debug" and doing nothing but re-running the code, it works well. Below is the code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Option Explicit

Public Function SheetFromCodeName(aName As String, wb As Workbook) As Worksheet

    Dim sh As Worksheet
    For Each sh In wb.Worksheets
        If sh.CodeName = aName Then
           Set SheetFromCodeName = sh
           Exit For
        End If
    Next sh

End Function

Sub Note_Transfer()


    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim MatchRow As Long
    Dim firstopenrow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim sh_old As Worksheet
    Dim sh_new As Worksheet
    Dim sh_DP_old As Worksheet
    Dim sh_DP_new As Worksheet
    Dim wb_old As Workbook
    Dim wb_new As Workbook

    Set wb_old = Workbooks(Workbooks.Count - 1)
    Set wb_new = Workbooks(Workbooks.Count)
    Set sh_old = SheetFromCodeName("Sheet1", wb_old)
    Set sh_new = SheetFromCodeName("Sheet1", wb_new)

' transfer note if record matches
    Set sh_DP_old = wb_old.Sheets("Discharged Patient")

    sh_DP_old.Copy After:=sh_new

    Set sh_DP_new = wb_new.Sheets("Discharged Patient")

    lastrow = sh_old.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To lastrow

    If sh_old.Cells(i, 25) <> "Discharged patient" Then

    MatchRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(sh_old.Cells(i, 23).Value, sh_new.Range("W:W"), 0)

    sh_new.Cells(MatchRow, 26).Resize(, 7).Value = sh_old.Cells(i, 26).Resize(, 7).Value

    Else

    firstopenrow = sh_DP_new.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    sh_DP_new.Cells(firstopenrow, 1).Resize(, 32).Value = sh_old.Cells(i, 1).Resize(, 32).Value

    End If
    Next

    sh_new.Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Your `SheetFromCodeName` returns `Nothing` if it cannot find the sheet, and you are not checking for `Nothing` before passing the result to `After:=`.

Comment: Set a breakpoint at ***sh_DP_old.Copy After:=sh_new***. Run. Examine sh_DP_old. Is it valid? etc ...

Comment: sh_DP_old is valid. However, it reports "Run-time error '91': Object variable or with block variable not set" when I check ?sh_new.Name.

Comment: Problem solved. First, click Trust access to the VBA project object model via Excel Macro settings. Second, replace 'Set sh_old = SheetFromCodeName("Sheet1", wb_old)
Set sh_new = SheetFromCodeName("Sheet1", wb_new)' with 'With wb_old
  Set sh_old = .Worksheets(CStr(.VBProject.VBComponents("Sheet1").Properties(7)))
End With
With wb_new
  Set sh_new = .Worksheets(CStr(.VBProject.VBComponents("Sheet1").Properties(7)))
End With'. And credit given to @John_Cunningham from Udemy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, click Trust access to the VBA project object model via Excel Macro settings. Second, replace

```
Set sh_old = SheetFromCodeName("Sheet1", wb_old) 
Set sh_new = SheetFromCodeName("Sheet1", wb_new)
```

with

```
With wb_old 
Set sh_old = .Worksheets(CStr(.VBProject.VBComponents("Sheet1").Properties(7))) 
End With 
With wb_new 
Set sh_new= .Worksheets(CStr(.VBProject.VBComponents("Sheet1").Properties(7)))
End With
```

And credit given to @John_Cunningham from Udemy.
Modified whole code is pasted below.

```
Option Explicit

Private Function SheetFromCodeName(aName As String, wb As Workbook) As Excel.Worksheet

    Dim sh As Worksheet
    For Each sh In wb.Worksheets
        If sh.CodeName = aName Then
           Set SheetFromCodeName = sh
           Exit For
        End If
    Next sh

End Function

Sub Note_Transfer()


    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim MatchRow As Long
    Dim firstopenrow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim sh_old As Worksheet
    Dim sh_new As Worksheet
    Dim sh_DP_old As Worksheet
    Dim sh_DP_new As Worksheet
    Dim wb_old As Workbook
    Dim wb_new As Workbook

    Set wb_old = Workbooks(Workbooks.Count - 1)
    Set wb_new = Workbooks(Workbooks.Count)

    With wb_old
    Set sh_old = .Worksheets(CStr(.VBProject.VBComponents("Sheet1").Properties(7)))
    End With
    With wb_new
    Set sh_new = .Worksheets(CStr(.VBProject.VBComponents("Sheet1").Properties(7)))
    End With

' transfer note if record matches
    Set sh_DP_old = wb_old.Sheets("Discharged Patient")

    sh_DP_old.Copy After:=sh_new

    Set sh_DP_new = wb_new.Sheets("Discharged Patient")

    lastrow = sh_old.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To lastrow

    If sh_old.Cells(i, 25) <> "Discharged patient" Then

    MatchRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(sh_old.Cells(i, 23).Value, sh_new.Range("W:W"), 0)

    sh_new.Cells(MatchRow, 26).Resize(, 7).Value = sh_old.Cells(i, 26).Resize(, 7).Value

    Else

    firstopenrow = sh_DP_new.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    sh_DP_new.Cells(firstopenrow, 1).Resize(, 32).Value = sh_old.Cells(i, 1).Resize(, 32).Value

    End If
    Next


    sh_new.Select

End Sub
```